# Magento: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object (1.5.1)

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.5

I am attempting to access one of my Magento Store's (Version 1.5.1) and I am getting the following error when I try and access it: 
Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in /home4/wisestor/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Resource.php on line 133.

```
Line 133 of Resource.php is:            
 return $this->_getWriteAdapter()->insert($this->getMainTable(), $dbModuleInfo);
```

Comment: Check your DB connection credentials in /app/etc/local.xml